# Reading response from GCDAsyncSocket on time (iOS)

Tags: ios, sockets, cocoaasyncsocket, gcdasyncsocket

This issue is pretty simple, I'm just having trouble figuring out how to handle it.

I read data with:

```
[asyncSocket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:2];

NSString *failure = [serverJSONResponseParsed objectForKey:@"failure"];
NSLog(@"Contents of string failure: %@", failure);

if ([failure isEqualToString:@"none"]) {
    NSLog(@"Success Sending String");
    return TRUE;
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@",failure);
    return FALSE;
}
```

Now, just as expected, my delegate method gets called and properly reads the JSON data:

```
-(void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag {
    NSError *error;
    NSLog(@"didReadData: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    serverJSONResponseParsed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSLog(@"didReadData test after dict: %@", [serverJSONResponseParsed objectForKey:@"failure"]);
}
```

The problem is, since GCDAsyncSocket is Asynchronous,
this block of code

```
NSString *failure = [serverJSONResponseParsed objectForKey:@"failure"];
NSLog(@"Contents of string failure: %@", failure);

if ([failure isEqualToString:@"none"]) {
    NSLog(@"Success Sending String");
    return TRUE;
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@",failure);
    return FALSE;
}
```

after

```
[asyncSocket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:2];
```

Is called before the data has a chance to be read in. How would I go about ensuring that the data is read, and then analyze it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That block of code needed to be in the didReadData callback method, like so:

```
    -(void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag {
        NSError *error;
        NSLog(@"didReadData: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        serverJSONResponseParsed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@"didReadData test after dict: %@", [serverJSONResponseParsed objectForKey:@"failure"]);

    NSString *failure = [serverJSONResponseParsed objectForKey:@"failure"];
    NSLog(@"Contents of string failure: %@", failure);

    if ([failure isEqualToString:@"none"]) {
        NSLog(@"Success Sending String");
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@",failure);
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate that you've answered almost all of my questions.